# How can I either fix HMR with Webpack 5 to not break my service worker, or exclude it from HMR?

Tags: webpack, service-worker, hot-module-replacement

I've added a service worker to my application for the very first time. Everything is working great. My only problem is Hot Module Reloading. Now, whenever it runs, it gives me a "document is not defined" error for my service worker and breaks the whole recompilation.

Here is a small snippet of my webpack config. I'm just compiling it and outputting it directly. This is also not the whole webpack config, just a piece of it.

```
const config = {
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    entry: {
        main: path.join(process.cwd(), 'src'),
        'service-worker': {
            import: path.join(process.cwd(), 'src', 'service-worker.ts'),
            filename: 'service-worker.js'
        }
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'build'),
        filename: 'assets/js/[name].[contenthash].js',
        chunkFilename: 'assets/js/[name].[contenthash].js',
        publicPath: process.env.WEBPACK_PUBLIC_PATH || '/'
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        hot: true
    }
};
```

I'm trying to figure out what my options are here. Is there some way to prevent HMR from breaking due to my service worker? Is there a way to exclude my service worker entirely from HMR, I would settle even for that?